# Invertible Matrix Theorem Proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing, inverse

I'm trying to prove the Invertible Matrix Theorem. The theorem that was given is as follows:

> For any $n\space x\space n$ matrix $A$, the following are equivalent:
>   1) $A$ is invertible 
>   2) The RREF of $A$ is $I$ 
>   3) rank $A = n$ 
>   4) The system of equations $A\vec{x} = \vec{b}$ is consistent with a unique solution for all $\vec{b}\in\mathbb{R}^n$ 
>   5) The nullspace of $A$ is $\left \{\vec{0}\right \}$ 
>   6) The columns of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
>   7) The rows of $A$ form a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ 
>   8) $A^T$ is invertible

I'm fine with everything up until I have to prove that 6 implies 7. My prof said that we should be able to prove all (or most?) of these through theorems and/or definitions.  I've look around for the proof of 6 implying 7 and a lot of them refer to the column rank being equal to the row rank which I don't think was covered in my class yet.  Any ideas on how to prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume toward a contradiction that the last row is a linear combination of the other rows. Now consider the first $n-1$ entries of the $n$ columns. These are $n$ vectors of size $n-1$, thus one is a combination of the others. This combination automatically extends to the last entry by the assumption. Thus we have a contradiction to independence of the columns.